# Criar um mini CRUD (básico) em tkinter com python

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

meu nome é Victor, já pesquisei sobre os Treeview mais não consegui fazer nada, mas o meu objetivo é esse aqui: Fiz um exemplo ilustrado

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

segue o código:

```
from tkinter import*

class principal:
    def __init__(self):

        janela_principal = Tk()
        janela_principal.geometry("700x575+50+50")
        janela_principal.title("PROTOCOLO DE DOCUMENTOS RECEBIDOS - PMPA - BPOT")
        #janela_principal.overrideredirect(True)

        txtNDocumento   = StringVar()
        txtAssunto      = StringVar()
        txtDQFR         = StringVar()

        a = Label(janela_principal)
        a.pack(side=TOP)

        b = Label(janela_principal)
        b.pack(side=BOTTOM)

        b1 = Label(janela_principal)
        b1.pack()

        c = Label(janela_principal)
        c.pack(pady=14)

        d = Label(b1, text="Nº do Documento:   ", font=("Gentium Basic", 11))
        d.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N)
        d1 = Entry(b1, width=20, textvariable=txtNDocumento, font=("Gentium Basic", 11), justify=CENTER)
        d1.grid(row=1, column=0)


        e = Label(b1, text="Assunto:   ", font=("Gentium Basic", 11))
        e.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N)
        e1 = Entry(b1, width=20, textvariable=txtAssunto, font=("Gentium Basic", 11))
    e1.grid(row=1, column=1)

        f = Label(b1, text="Data que foi recebido:", font=("Gentium Basic", 11))
        f.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=N)
        f1 = Entry(b1, width=20, textvariable=txtDQFR, font=("Gentium Basic", 11))
        f1.grid(row=1, column=2)

        g = Button(b1, text="ADICIONAR", width=12, height=2, relief=FLAT,  activebackground="#4169E1", activeforeground="WHITE", background="#4169E1", foreground="WHITE")
        g.grid(row=0, column=3, rowspan=2, padx=15)



        rolagem = Scrollbar(c)
        rolagem.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N+S)

        caixa_exibição = Listbox(c, relief=SOLID, border=1, width=80, height=25, font=("Gentium Basic", 11))
        caixa_exibição.grid(row=0, column=0)


        #for i in range(100):
        #    caixa_exibição.insert(END, i)

        # attach listbox to scrollbar
        caixa_exibição.config(yscrollcommand=rolagem.set)
        rolagem.config(command=caixa_exibição.yview)

        janela_principal.mainloop()

principal()
```

Comment: E como ficou? Qual é o problema? O que espera responder com esta pergunta?

Comment: Sinceramente, eu não consigo encaixar o banco de dados, e nem fazer a Listbox como está ilustrado na imagem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um código de exemplo seguindo como base a imagem que você postou, contudo não segui pelo seu código de base.

Vale notar que busquei a solução mais simples e não a mais otimizada.

Todo o código está em um **único arquivo**, depois você pode otimizar isso, bem como criar as validações que julgar necessárias.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""Exemplo treeview + SQLite3"""
import re
import sqlite3
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as tkk
from tkinter import messagebox


class ConectarDB:
    def __init__(self):
        self.con = sqlite3.connect('db.sqlite3')
        self.cur = self.con.cursor()
        self.criar_tabela()

    def criar_tabela(self):
        try:
            self.cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS NomeDaTabela (
                n_documento TEXT,
                assunto TEXT,
                data TEXT)''')
        except Exception as e:
            print('[x] Falha ao criar tabela: %s [x]' % e)
        else:
            print('\n[!] Tabela criada com sucesso [!]\n')

    def inserir_registro(self, ndocumento, assunto, data):
        try:
            self.cur.execute(
                '''INSERT INTO NomeDaTabela VALUES (?, ?, ?)''', (ndocumento, assunto, data,))
        except Exception as e:
            print('\n[x] Falha ao inserir registro [x]\n')
            print('[x] Revertendo operação (rollback) %s [x]\n' % e)
            self.con.rollback()
        else:
            self.con.commit()
            print('\n[!] Registro inserido com sucesso [!]\n')

    def consultar_registros(self):
        return self.cur.execute('SELECT rowid, * FROM NomeDaTabela').fetchall()

    def consultar_ultimo_rowid(self):
        return self.cur.execute('SELECT MAX(rowid) FROM NomeDaTabela').fetchone()

    def remover_registro(self, rowid):
        try:
            self.cur.execute("DELETE FROM NomeDaTabela WHERE rowid=?", (rowid,))
        except Exception as e:
            print('\n[x] Falha ao remover registro [x]\n')
            print('[x] Revertendo operação (rollback) %s [x]\n' % e)
            self.con.rollback()
        else:
            self.con.commit()
            print('\n[!] Registro removido com sucesso [!]\n')


class Janela(tk.Frame):
    """Janela principal"""

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        """Construtor"""
        super().__init__(master)
        # Coletando informações do monitor
        largura = round(self.winfo_screenwidth() / 2)
        altura = round(self.winfo_screenheight() / 2)
        tamanho = ('%sx%s' % (largura, altura))

        # Título da janela principal.
        master.title('Exemplo')

        # Tamanho da janela principal.
        master.geometry(tamanho)

        # Instanciando a conexão com o banco.
        self.banco = ConectarDB()

        # Gerenciador de layout da janela principal.
        self.pack()

        # Criando os widgets da interface.
        self.criar_widgets()

    def criar_widgets(self):
        # Containers.
        frame1 = tk.Frame(self)
        frame1.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, padx=5, pady=5)

        frame2 = tk.Frame(self)
        frame2.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        frame3 = tk.Frame(self)
        frame3.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, padx=5)

        # Labels.
        label_documento = tk.Label(frame1, text='N° Documento')
        label_documento.grid(row=0, column=0)

        label_assunto = tk.Label(frame1, text='Assunto')
        label_assunto.grid(row=0, column=1)

        label_recebido = tk.Label(frame1, text='Data recebimento')
        label_recebido.grid(row=0, column=2)

        # Entrada de texto.
        self.entry_documento = tk.Entry(frame1)
        self.entry_documento.grid(row=1, column=0)

        self.entry_assunto = tk.Entry(frame1)
        self.entry_assunto.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10)

        self.entry_data = tk.Entry(frame1)
        self.entry_data.grid(row=1, column=2)

        # Botão para adicionar um novo registro.
        button_adicionar = tk.Button(frame1, text='Adicionar', bg='blue', fg='white')
        # Método que é chamado quando o botão é clicado.
        button_adicionar['command'] = self.adicionar_registro
        button_adicionar.grid(row=0, column=3, rowspan=2, padx=10)

        # Treeview.
        self.treeview = tkk.Treeview(frame2, columns=('N° documento', 'Assunto', 'Data'))
        self.treeview.heading('#0', text='ROWID')
        self.treeview.heading('#1', text='N° documento')
        self.treeview.heading('#2', text='Assunto')
        self.treeview.heading('#3', text='Data')

        # Inserindo os dados do banco no treeview.
        for row in self.banco.consultar_registros():
            self.treeview.insert('', 'end', text=row[0], values=(row[1], row[2], row[3]))

        self.treeview.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        # Botão para remover um item.
        button_excluir = tk.Button(frame3, text='Excluir', bg='red', fg='white')
        # Método que é chamado quando o botão é clicado.
        button_excluir['command'] = self.excluir_registro
        button_excluir.pack(pady=10)

    def adicionar_registro(self):
        # Coletando os valores.
        documento = self.entry_documento.get()
        assunto = self.entry_assunto.get()
        data = self.entry_data.get()

        # Validação simples (utilizar datetime deve ser melhor para validar).
        validar_data = re.search(r'(..)/(..)/(....)', data)

        # Se a data digitada passar na validação
        if validar_data:
            # Dados digitando são inseridos no banco de dados
            self.banco.inserir_registro(ndocumento=documento, assunto=assunto, data=data)

            # Coletando a ultima rowid que foi inserida no banco.
            rowid = self.banco.consultar_ultimo_rowid()[0]

            # Adicionando os novos dados no treeview.
            self.treeview.insert('', 'end', text=rowid, values=(documento, assunto, data))
        else:
            # Caso a data não passe na validação é exibido um alerta.
            messagebox.showerror('Erro', 'Padrão de data incorreto, utilize dd/mm/yyyy')

    def excluir_registro(self):
        # Verificando se algum item está selecionado.
        if not self.treeview.focus():
            messagebox.showerror('Erro', 'Nenhum item selecionado')
        else:
            # Coletando qual item está selecionado.
            item_selecionado = self.treeview.focus()

            # Coletando os dados do item selecionado (dicionário).
            rowid = self.treeview.item(item_selecionado)

            # Removendo o item com base no valor do rowid (argumento text do treeview).
            # Removendo valor da tabela.
            self.banco.remover_registro(rowid['text'])

            # Removendo valor do treeview.
            self.treeview.delete(item_selecionado)


root = tk.Tk()
app = Janela(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```